# How to listen for when a youtube video goes from unstarted to playing for 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have the following code below which prints to console when the video is playing for 5 seconds.  However, if the user pauses the video and then presses play again it gets printed to the console.

How do I only print to console when the status goes from unstarted to playing for 5 seconds?

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
     ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    if (newState == 1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            current = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
            console.log(current);
        }, 5000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onStateChange` handler gets triggered for all sorts of player state changes, not just "playing" events: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#onStateChange

You would need to modify your `onytplayerStateChange()` function to listen for "paused"/"buffering" events and suspend your countdown when those are fired, and only restart it when the next "playing" event is fired.